# Can Totem Beast Feat Be Taken Multiple Times?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, animal-companions

While recently creating a Packlord type character build, I stumbled upon this the [Totem Beast](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/totem-beast/) feat. It doesn't explicitly state that it can be taken multiple times, but it also seems to assume the character in question will only have one animal companion, where a packlord type can have multiple. The Boon Companion feat reflects that well, and lets you take it one time per companion.

Would it be legal to take Totem Beast several times, as long as it applied to a different companion each time?

A related question, which doesn't address the multiple companions issue: [How does the Pathfinder Druid's Totem Beast feat work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96575/how-does-the-pathfinder-druids-totem-beast-feat-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No

The feat doesn't say you can take it multiple times, so you cannot take it multiple times.

Even personally outside of a RAW perspective, getting the feat for separate companions would be pushing on too strong; stat bonuses are relatively sparse for companions, getting an automatically-scaling bonus to every companion is pretty impactful, even if it takes a feat per bonus.

Answer (score 1):

RAW, feats can only be taken once without explicit wording to the contrary (hence the existence of such wording).

This GM would be inclined to allow a character to take the feat multiple times, once per companion: none of the boons look to be overpowered and there are other feats that (were I playing a Druid) I'd have to weigh carefully against this one (that is to say that giving a second animal companion a boon from this feat isn't clearly better than, say, Spell Penetration or Combat Reflexes).

Answer (score 1):

Unless it is explicitly stated otherwise, a feat can only be taken once. Some can be taken multiple times with a different option every time (such as Weapon Focus), some can be taken multiple times with stacking effects (such as Extra Ki), any feat without any such explicit wording can only be taken once.